# Всем привет. Как в Unity считать нажатие кнопки Play/Stop (назовем её так) на наушниках телефона (гарнитура обычная). Для системы Android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Всё что мне надо: обработать инпут кнопки гарнитуры. всё.
Чаты в стиле GPT закидывают нерабочим кодом, на форумах пусто, на ютубчике и близко ничего не нашёл:( Явно вопрос плёвый, но уже полдня на него убил и меня это дико злит.

Comment: По сути, требуется сначала считать эти самые коды кнопок, которые поступают с гарнитуры, если я правильно втыкаю. Написать самописный сканер клавиш, получить код клавиши, а затем уже обрабатывать само нажатие с помощью кей-кода.

Comment: Да, я такую фишку проворачивать пытался. Не прокатило. не происходит считывание. Гарнитура исправна.

Comment: [тык](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons)

Comment: Это здорово, но как мне это с юнькой увязать?) Я пока продолжал свои поиски - понял, что вопрос нифига не плёвый, как я думал) там и на java надо скриптик накидать и апишки андройдовские пошариться поискать и всё это надо в одной кастрюле еще сварить....

Comment: Так ищите и варите, в этом кайф программирования

Comment: Как один из вариантов посмотреть библиотеки для подключения сторонние можно попробовать